# Splitting text file based on column value in unix

Tags: unix, awk, split, grep

I have a text file:

```
head train_test_split.txt 
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 1
5 1
```

What I want to do is save the first column values for which second column value is 1 to file `train.txt`.

So, the corresponding first column value for second column value with 1 are: 2,4,5. So, in my train.txt file i want:

```
2
4
5
```

How can I do this easily unix?

Comment: does your `grep` support `-P` (--perl-regexp) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '$2 == 1 { print $1 }' inputfile
```

That is,
`$2 == 1` is a filter,
matching lines where the 2nd column is 1,
and `print $1` means to print the first column.

Comment: Or just the 'truthiness' of `$2` will work: `awk '$2{print $1}'`

Comment: @dawg for the given sample yes, but it was not specified that the 2nd column will only have 0 and 1 values.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
$ perl -lane 'print "$F[0]" if $F[1]==1' file
```

Or GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP '^(\S+)(?=[ \t]+1$)' file
```

But `awk` is the best. Use awk...

Comment: the grep one can be simplified to `grep -oP '^\S+(?=\h+1$)'`